# Use different style for each figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

is it possible to use a different matplotlib style for each figure I create within a script?

```
with plt.style.context("style.mpstyle"):
    ...
```

can be used to define a temporary custom style in matplotlib. I'm using this in a class, which should handle all my styles:

```
class Plots():
    def __init__(self):
        if style == "a":
            self.use_style_a()
        else:
            self.use_style_b()

    def use_style_a():
        with plt.style.context("style_a.mpstyle"):
            self.fig = plt.figure()
            [...]

    def use_style_b():
        with plt.style.context("style_b.mpstyle"):
            self.fig = plt.figure()
            [...]
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't really work. Or it's only working 50%... so if I call plt.legend() outside of the initial function call, it's not applying the style from the external style file.
So is there a way to apply the figure style to that figure instance, no matter from where I call it?

## Solution

ImportanceOfBeingErnest gave me the right hint, which I now use in a modified way. Unfortunately, the `mpl.style.context()` method doesn't work in this case - I don't know why. But I can just always overwrite the style to use. Probably not the mpl creators intention to use, but it works. Here my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Plot(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.plot_style = name

        func = getattr(self, name)
        result = func()

    def A(self):
        plt.style.use("A.mpstyle")
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

        # Some styles, labels, ...

    def B(self):
        plt.style.use("B.mpstyle")
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

        # Some styles, labels, ...

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == "ax":
            plt.style.use("{}.mpstyle".format(self.plot_style))
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        else:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

plot_A = Plot("A")
plot_B = Plot("B")

plot_A.ax.plot([1,2,4],[4,2,3])
plot_B.ax.plot([1,2,4],[3,1,6])
plot_A.ax.legend()
plot_B.ax.legend()

# ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It think it all depends on how you want to use this class. An option, if you want to create the same plot, but with different styles, would be the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Plots():
    def __init__(self, style):
        self.set_style(style)
        self.plot()

    def set_style(self, style):
        self.style = "style_{}.mpstyle".format(style)

    def plot(self):
        with plt.style.context(self.style):
            self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
            self.ax.plot([1,2,4])
            self.ax.legend()
            plt.show()

p = Plots("a")
p2 = Plots("b")
```

I could also imagine that you want to use different functions to do the actual plotting and use a class to manage the styles.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Plots():
    def __init__(self, style="a"):
        self.set_style(style)

    def set_style(self, style):
        self.style = style

    def plot(self, func, *args,**kwargs):
        with plt.style.context(self.style):
            return func(*args,**kwargs)

def myplottingfunction1():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot([1,2,4],[4,2,3], label="mylabel 1")
    ax.legend()

def myplottingfunction2(color="red"):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter([1,2,4],[3,1,6], color=color,label="mylabel 2")
    ax.legend()


p = Plots("dark_background").plot(myplottingfunction1)
p2 = Plots("ggplot").plot(myplottingfunction2, color="blue")

plt.show()
```

The output of this second script would be

[image]

Of course the legend can be plotted separately, e.g. like

```
def myplottingfunction1():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot([1,2,4],[4,2,3], label="mylabel 1")
    return ax

def myplottingfunction2(color="red"):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter([1,2,4],[3,1,6], color=color,label="mylabel 2")
    return ax

p = Plots("dark_background")
ax = p.plot(myplottingfunction1)
p2 = Plots("ggplot")
ax2 = p2.plot(myplottingfunction2, color="blue")

# do something else with ax or ax2

p.plot(ax.legend)
p2.plot(ax2.legend)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your 2nd solution heads into the right direction. However, it does not completely solve my issue. I need the flexibility to change the data set and do custom modifications in my script later. But these modification of my standard styleset (for each data set type) are not done with the styleset. For example: I take your example, but by default I don't have a legend. But in some cases, when I want to plot multiple datasets in one figure, I have to add a legend with plt.legend(). Unfortunately, this legend then does not use the style from the stylesheet.

Comment: The requirements are rather handwavy. I added how you would use the code to style the legend later on.

Comment: Thanks again, looks like this should(!) work now. Unfortunately, it isn't. It is not taking any legend style info from the stylesheet (e.g., legend.facecolor: k is defined, but facecolor is still white). Maybe it's a bug, I'll try it at home where I have a different python version running.